# Express server launches in heroku development not on actual heroku server

Tags: javascript, express, heroku

Dear All I hope you can help.  I have been trying to launch some code from the following website so I can take stripe payments on my website.

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/

I can launch this code perfectly in a heroku server but when it comes to launching it for real it failed.  I have run the heroku logs --tail command and it identifies en error on the following piece of code in here (CORS_WHITELIST.indexOf(origin) !== -1). This error states that CORS_WHITELIST is not a function.

Does anyone know what is wrong with it please?

Code on GitHub as follows: -

https://github.com/gilesgerman/stokpixexpress

```js
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const CORS_WHITELIST = require('./constants/frontend');

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) =>
    (CORS_WHITELIST.indexOf(origin) !== -1)
      ? callback(null, true)
      : callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
};

const configureServer = app => {
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
};

module.exports = configureServer;
```

Apologies for not including this the error message is as follows: -

```js
MacBook-Pro:backend gilesgerman$ heroku logs --tail
2018-04-24T22:13:39.925437+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-04-24T22:13:42.270699+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-04-24T22:13:42.270718+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start /app
2018-04-24T22:13:42.270720+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2018-04-24T22:13:42.270722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-04-24T22:13:42.557274+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running on port: 38179
2018-04-24T22:13:43.524801+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-24T22:13:51.699607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-shelf-79441.herokuapp.com request_id=b84196c4-0532-4071-b3d5-35f250bf564f fwd="89.206.243.24" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703709+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Not allowed by CORS
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at origin (/app/server.js:11:18)
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703723+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703726+00:00 app[web.1]:     at optionsCallback (/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703728+00:00 app[web.1]:     at corsMiddleware (/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703729+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703731+00:00 app[web.1]:     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703732+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703734+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703735+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2018-04-24T22:13:51.703737+00:00 app[web.1]:     at expressInit (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
2018-04-24T22:13:52.052621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-shelf-79441.herokuapp.com request_id=d05bd243-9059-4e3b-8e5c-9571d66af3c5 fwd="89.206.243.24" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055055+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Not allowed by CORS
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055073+00:00 app[web.1]:     at origin (/app/server.js:11:18)
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055075+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055077+00:00 app[web.1]:     at optionsCallback (/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055079+00:00 app[web.1]:     at corsMiddleware (/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055081+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055083+00:00 app[web.1]:     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055084+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055086+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055087+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2018-04-24T22:13:52.055089+00:00 app[web.1]:     at expressInit (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.615705+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-shelf-79441.herokuapp.com request_id=04daf749-6049-421d-883d-060e6f52b4ef fwd="89.206.243.24" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618191+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Not allowed by CORS
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618209+00:00 app[web.1]:     at origin (/app/server.js:11:18)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618225+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618227+00:00 app[web.1]:     at optionsCallback (/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618229+00:00 app[web.1]:     at corsMiddleware (/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618231+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618232+00:00 app[web.1]:     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618234+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618236+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618237+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777561+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Not allowed by CORS
2018-04-24T22:13:55.618239+00:00 app[web.1]:     at expressInit (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777565+00:00 app[web.1]:     at origin (/app/server.js:11:18)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777567+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777569+00:00 app[web.1]:     at optionsCallback (/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777571+00:00 app[web.1]:     at corsMiddleware (/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777573+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777575+00:00 app[web.1]:     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777576+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777579+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777580+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.777582+00:00 app[web.1]:     at expressInit (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
2018-04-24T22:13:55.775109+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-shelf-79441.herokuapp.com request_id=43f22947-6225-4a89-b3b4-f4a2e18ccd59 fwd="89.206.243.24" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
```

Comment: Can you please update your post with the actual error message you are seeing? Thanks.

Comment: Please put the ACTUAL and EXACT error message in your question.  It amazes me that people so often leave out this very important piece of information as that's usually the main clue about what is wrong.  We also need to know exactly which line of code the error is complaining about.

Comment: I'd also ask if `CORS_WHITELIST` is getting a proper value in your production environment. If you do `console.log(CORS_WHITELIST)` does it show you what you expect in the production environment?

Comment: I have updated this as requested.